# Problema enviar correos Plesk

Tags: email

Estoy intentando activar un servidor de correo en Plesk para uno de los dominios alojados en él, recibo correos perfectamente puedo loguear al webmail pero cuando trato de enviar un correo me da el siguiente error:

Error SMTP (454): No se pudo establecer destinatario "destinatario@gmail.com" (4.7.1 : Relay access denied).

¿alguien sabe porque de este error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es entrar en el archivo de configuración de postfix y cambiar $config['user']= '%u'

por

$config['user'] = ''